# ECS auto scaling: scale down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I'm working on configuring auto-scaling for ECS, and wanted to know during scale down if a task that is being brought down had a containerized service which had few request to be processed, will these requests be processed or will the task be dropped immediately?

Any answer or pointing to right AWS documentation will really help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using ECS with a combination of AWS ALB/Target groups? If yes, then check [target group deregistration delay](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#deregistration-delay). You can configure this time, before your task will be stopped. During deregistration no more new connections will be added to your task, this ensure existing requests have enough time to be processed.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlinAndrei, your suggestion is helping I'll verify the same in actual deployment and will get back on this.

Comment: @AlinAndrei I have a follow up question I got while validating. Since I'm using ECS in EC2 hosted mode and have set Auto scaling for EC2 as well, i'm trying to understand what will happen if the EC2 instance scales in and there is a active task running on it or will this not happen?

Comment: From AWS Documentation: Amazon ECS cluster auto scaling enables you to have more control over how you scale the Amazon EC2 instances within a cluster. When creating an Auto Scaling group capacity provider with managed scaling enabled, Amazon ECS manages the scale-in and scale-out actions of the Auto Scaling group used when creating the capacity provider. On your behalf, Amazon ECS creates an AWS Auto Scaling scaling plan with a target tracking scaling policy based on the target capacity value you specify.

Comment: As long as you follow the mention above, you won't have to worry about scale in/out operations as ECS manages the EC2 auto scaling group .More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html)

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/containers/graceful-shutdowns-with-ecs/).

> When a task is stopped, a SIGTERM signal is sent to each container’s entry process, usually PID 1. After a timeout has lapsed, the process will be sent a SIGKILL signal. By default, there is a `30 second delay` between the delivery of SIGTERM and SIGKILL signals. This value can be adjusted by updating the ECS task parameter stopTimeout, or with EC2 Container Instances by setting the ECS agent environment variable ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT. Processes that don’t exit before the timeout expires will be terminated abruptly upon receipt of the SIGKILL signal.

By default, it will wait for the process dead until 30 seconds.

Comment: Okay got it, I have another question on this. Since I'm using ECS in EC2 hosted mode and have set Auto scaling for EC2 as well, i'm trying to understand what will happen if the EC2 instance scales in and there is a active task running on it or will this not happen?

Comment: Same as before. It will wait for some time and if the task is not properly terminated, then it will kill by force and terminate the instance, I think.